# How to align contents within table cells vertically?

Tags: tables, align

Sorry for opening up another thread when there are so many already, but I can't find the correct solution to this right now.

I would like to align the contents of the third column (the parts put in braces) vertically. What is the best way to do that?

Example:

```
\documentclass [titlepage,a4paper,12pt]{article}                                                              \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                                        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}      
\begin{document}  
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
    Name & Umsatz (in Euro, o. Ikea) & Umsatz (in Euro, m. Ikea)   \\ \hline
    M"obel-G"unther &  8.264.620  &   6.983.137 ($- \, 1.281.483$) \\ \hline
    Ikea            &  --         &  10.143.189 ($+ \, 10.143.189$) \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: I'm not sure what alignment you need, do you mean just have a fourth column, with an extra `l` in the tabular preamble and a `&` before each `(` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. Sorry for being unclear, I will do better next time. Thank you for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use four columns for your table and let the header "Umsatz mit Ikea" span columns 3 and 4. By using the column type `r` for columns 3 and 4 you'll get the natural alignement for the turnover numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                                        
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcrr}
    Name & Umsatz ohne Ikea  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Umsatz mit Ikea} \\ 
         & (in Euro)         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(in Euro)}\\
    \midrule
    M"obel-G"unther &  8.264.620  &   6.983.137 &  ($-1.281.483$) \\ 
    Ikea            &  --         &  10.143.189 & ($+10.143.189$) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I've chosen this as the best answer not only because of the aesthetics but also because this goes best with my very limited knowledge about LaTeX. Thanks to everyone else though, I really appreciate your time and effort! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the 'siunitx' package and the I included feature of having automated number alignments by means of the table column type S.

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                                        
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}  
\begin{center}
\sisetup{
    table-format = 10.0,
%   group-separator={.}
}
\begin{tabular}{lcSS[retain-explicit-plus]}
    Name & Umsatz ohne Ikea  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Umsatz mit Ikea} \\ 
         & (in Euro)         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(in Euro)}\\
    \midrule
    M"obel-G"unther &  8264620  &   6983137 &  -1281483 \\ 
    Ikea            &  --         &  10143189 & +10143189 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By using the now outcommented option of `group-separator` you may have groups of digits separated by e.g. a dot. Since you have a german document this might not be the mathematically correct option. You may concern that. 
Pleae note that the 'Umsatz ohne Ikea' columns wasn't gtreated with siunitx to show the difference. It's just plain text without markers. you may use `\num[options]{value}` just for this single number, instead of having a whole S-column. 
Also - since I have no more time today - you may experiment with positioning the explicit signs in the last column. There must be a way to get them left aligned and having the numbers right aligned. Please hold on to the huge siunitx manual.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the brackets around the numbers in last column.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mico that you may need a fourth column, but I have another suggestion for the alignment of the 3rd and 4th columns. Since the 3rd column contains numbers, it is better justified right and the numbers between the parentheses in the 4th column should be left justified with a single space `{ }` after the 3rd column to make the two columns appear as one. Here is what I think is better in your case:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                                        
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcr@{ }l}
\toprule
Name            &  Umsatz ohne Ikea (in Euro) & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Umsatz mit Ikea (in Euro)} \\  \midrule
M"obel-G"unther &  8.264.620                  &   6.983.137  &  ($-1.281.483$) \\ 
Ikea            &  --                         &  10.143.189  & ($+10.143.189$) \\   
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And here is the table:

[image]